# C#: Is there a winforms way to make C# MessageBox Buttons (YesNo) larger?

Tags: c#, winforms, messagebox

It would be nice to have larger MessageBox Buttons since the target for this application is a tablet.

```
DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show(
    message, caption,
    MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
    MessageBoxIcon.Question,
    MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button2);
switch (dialogResult)
{
    case DialogResult.Yes:
        // ...
```

Comment: you'd probably have to roll your own popup control

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is a system setting.  Tablet PCs are normally already configured to make it easy to tap buttons like this so that it works well in any program, not just yours.  To configure your tablet, in Win7, use Control Panel + Display, Personalization, Window Color.  Click Advanced appearance settings, select "Message Box" in the Item combo.  Increase the font size.  Don't be fooled by the poor preview, the button will actually grow.  There are additional settings in this dialog you might want to tweak to make it easier to manipulate the UI.

Comment: +1 If this works this is probably the best, and easiest, solution.

Comment: +1 It's the right thing to do, as I said, but you actually *knew* how to do it! Kudos!

Answer (score 4):

A messagebox is just a simple modal form. You can make one yourself and use `ShowDialog()`

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if it's possible or not, but you could use a simple form instead of a dialog box then you can get the design exactly as you wish.

Answer (score 2):

Winforms way? Do you mean, an "automagically via a property change" way? If so, none that I know of.

You can spin up your own custom dialog/form that is bigger and use it instead. While this is not as automagic as the one line MessageBox.Show(), it is not very difficult.

Answer (score 2):

That's not possible with `MessageBox` which wraps the native system dialog.

You'll need to produce your own dialog or even better see if there is a way to configure the system to give your app (and all others) bigger buttons.

The downside of rolling your own is that you lose all the functionality that the native one provides.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, going along with what MattP said, you'll need to create a custom form and then use the ShowDialog() method to display the second form as a modal dialog.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e) {
    using (Form2 xForm = new Form2()) {
        if (xForm.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK) {
            // Take some action

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make a 2nd form, then you can make the buttons as big as you want